# LINQ - Place part of a query that is always the same in a separate class and use in other linq queries

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

**Current situation**

Currently I have this `Linq` query:

```
return from function in this.context.Functions
               join fp in this.context.FunctionParameters on function.FunctionID equals fp.FunctionID into functionParameters
               from functionParameter in functionParameters.DefaultIfEmpty()
               join d in this.context.Descriptions on new
                {
                    ID = (int)function.FunctionID,
                    languageID = languageID,
                    originID = (byte)origin
                }
                equals new
                {
                    ID = d.ValueID,
                    languageID = d.LanguageID,
                    originID = d.OriginID
                }
                into entityWithDescription
               from x in entityWithDescription.DefaultIfEmpty()
               select new FunctionDTO()
               {
                   Function = function,
                   Description = x
               };
```

This returns the functions with their parameters and the specific descriptions. So, a select with two left outer joins. 
This is all good and works.

**The problem**

I have multiple objects that have a description. The description table has no relationship with these objects (so no FK). 
So there is a part of the above query that is **always** the same, namely the join query to the description table:

```
join d in this.context.Descriptions on new
            {
                ID = (int)function.FunctionID,
                languageID = languageID,
                originID = (byte)origin
            }
            equals new
            {
                ID = d.ValueID,
                languageID = d.LanguageID,
                originID = d.OriginID
            }
            into entityWithDescription
```

The variables `languageID` and `origin` are two parameters that are passed on with the method. The `FunctionID` is a property in my `Function` class, ie a property in my `entity model`. So that is a

```
public partial class Function
{
    public byte FunctionID { get; set; }

    /** Other properties **/
}
```

**My question**

Is it possible to create a separate class with the part of the `linq` query that is always the same? So that I don't have to duplicate the same code all over again?

**What I already tried**

```
var query = from function in this.context.Functions
               join fp in this.context.FunctionParameters on function.FunctionID equals fp.FunctionID into functionParameters
               from functionParameter in functionParameters.DefaultIfEmpty()
               select function;

        var testResult = this.context.Descriptions.GetDescriptionsByJoin(query, languageID, origin);
```

And the duplicate code in a separate class:

```
public static IQueryable<IEnumerable<Description>> GetDescriptionsByJoin(
        this IDbSet<Description> descriptions, IQueryable<ITranslatable> query, byte languageID, OriginEnum origin)
    {
        return from q in query
               join d in descriptions on new
                       {
                           ID = q.ValueID,
                           languageID = languageID,
                           originID = (byte)origin
                       }
                       equals new
                       {
                           ID = d.ValueID,
                           languageID = d.LanguageID,
                           originID = d.OriginID
                       }
                       into entityWithDescription
               select entityWithDescription;
    }
```

But this gave me the following error:

```
The specified type member is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported
```

I know that I get this error because I use my 'valueID' as a parameter in my join statement and that variable can't be found in my entity model (valueID is a property in an interface 'ITranslatable' that all my classes that have descriptions will implement).

Thanks in advance!

Greetings 
Loetn

Comment: Have you looked at LinqKit? It's on nuget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are after is [LinqKit](http://www.nuget.org/packages/LinqKit/).

EF is funny about the expressions it is able to translate into SQL. LinqKit has a built-in expression visitor that helps with these things.

You don't end up creating separate classes for the queries, but rather separate methods. You can then chain them together using the LinqKit-provided extension methods.

Never seen it used with query syntax though (`from x in foo where bar select x`), I have always used it with extension method syntax (`foo.Where(bar)`).